# Backspace not do not delete anything when contentEditable="true"

Tags: contenteditable

BACKSPACE does not delete text in a DIV where contentEditable="true".

The thing is that it is working when I do it in a simple test page like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div contenteditable="true">
            test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it is not working in my web application. My intuition is that some parent DIV create a conflict in term css or eventHandler. I don't have access to all the parent DIV css style (too many DIV) and same problem for the eventHandler.

What could create this bug?

All the other key event work correctly even DELETE is working. BACKSPACE works also but only to remove an empty line (after deleting its content with DELETE).

Any idea?